# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ such that $f(x)$ is rational for every $x$. What can be said about $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

can someone help me out with this question? I have been stuck on it for a while.

> Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[a, b]$, and that $f(x)$ is rational for every $x$ in the set $[a, b]$. What can be said about $f$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f$ must be constant.

Since $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is connected and compact, then $f([a,b])$ is connected and compact. Hence $f([a,b])$ is an interval, that is $f([a,b])=[c,d]$ for some $c,d$. If $c<d$, then that means $f([a,b])$ contains some irrational, which is a contradiction. Hence $c=d$, and $f(x) = c$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Intermediate Value Theorem, and the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $f([a,b])$ is a countable connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.